# 500 - Internal server error. PHP Submit page

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

I have a PHP page with many controls. The page loads fine with data from the database. But when I submit the page I am getting 500- Internal server error. I turned on 'Display Errors' in PHP.ini file. But still I get 500 error. I wrote a simple test page to insert the data, the page works fine. I don't see any errors in php_errors.log file. How can I find the problem? Please let me know if there are any ideas. The page worked fine with 5.3.8. I just upgraded to 5.3.10. Thank you for any help. I am new to PHP and I am using the Dreamweaver.

Comment: What does your web server's error log say?

Comment: turn on "display_errors" and "display_startup_errors" in php.ini and then make sure you restart the web server.

Comment: where can I find the error log for web server?

Comment: @nav100: Please consult the product documentation of your webserver.

Comment: I turned "display_errors" but still I am getting 500 error.

Comment: Dreamweaver now uses FastCGI for its shared hosting.  Have you got your permission on your script correct?  You need to ensure that it is not writeable by anyone other than owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could do with some debugging.  There is an [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011008/debugging-php-code) about debugging PHP code in Dreamweaver.